# Lucene 3.6 and custom Tokenizer/Analizer for special chars

Tags: java, search, indexing, lucene

I am using Lucene 3.6 and **StandardAnalyzer** in my project for Index and Search. Such analizer split search query string by all special chars (@, #, -, _).

For example: if I will serach "somename@gmail.com #2nd place", tokenizer create such query string: *[somename][gmail][com][2nd][place]*. But I need string like this one:*[somename@gmail][com][#2nd][place]*.

So how to exclude such special char from stop chars?

And one question: I need re-index all with new analizer or just can use new analizer with old index?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`StandardAnalyzer` uses `StandardTokenizer` for defining grammar rules (word breaks etc.). [Documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html) of the latter says:

> Many applications have specific tokenizer needs. If this tokenizer
>   does not suit your application, please consider copying this source
>   code directory to your project and maintaining your own grammar-based
>   tokenizer.

Quickly peeking into `StandardTokenizer` code I could guess that removing `"<EMAIL>"` from `TOKEN_TYPES` might be sufficient. Or maybe not :-)

And yes, you will need to reindex.

Comment: Hmm.. What will be if I just run indexer with new analizer for new files  and without reindexing old files? Cannot update index file or I just can't find some staff that was in old files?

Comment: The general practice is that you should run *exactly* the same procedure for both indexing and querying. If you keep old records without reindexing, they will not likely be found with the new analyzer -- but this is just a wild guess, don't quote me on this!

Comment: Yes, but if I will serach just two words ("second place") - both analyzers will create exactly the same tokens. Question only if idexer with new analizer can update idex file.
Thanks for answers!